# lvalue required as left operand of assignment c

Tags: c

at this code

```
(nr % 10) % 2 == 0 ? a[i] = nr % 10 + 1 : a[i] = nr % 10;
```

I get a `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `a[i] = (nr % 10) + 1 - ((nr % 10) % 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put parentheses around your last assignment to solve this:

```
(nr % 10) % 2 == 0 ? a[i] = nr % 10 + 1 : (a[i] = nr % 10);
```

This is because assignment has a lower precedence than the ternary operator so code like `a = b ? d : c` is parsed as `a = (b ? c : d)` and not as `(a = b) ? c : d`. The assignment between `?` and `:` doesn't need to be placed in parentheses as there isn't any syntactic ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The overall problem with this code is that conditional operator is an *expression*, not a *statement*. Although you can use assignment expressions as its part, it's better to do the assignment of the whole expression, like this:

```
a[i] = (nr % 2) == 0 ? nr % 10 + 1 : nr % 10;
//     ^^^^^^^^
// No need to obtain a remainder of division by 10,
// because 2 is a divisor of 10.
```

**Note:** You could avoid the conditional altogether with a simple trick:

```
a[i] = nr % 10 + (1 - (nr % 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
a[i] = (nr % 10) % 2 == 0 ? nr % 10 + 1 : nr % 10;
```